# Modal is working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Modal is working in Firefox but not in Chrome, I added the code below.

1. The following is my app.js :

```
$('.test').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     $('#join-req').modal();
      });
```

2. HTML :

```
<a href="#" class="test">Join to my Group</a>
```

3. The modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="join-req">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Join Request</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="post-body">Join request to expert</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="join-body" id="join-body" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-save">Submit request</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The following are the Bootstrap and jquery links :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('src/css/main.css') }}">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::to('src/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well what error do you get in Chrome. Do you see any errors in developers's console?. Include a screenshot if possible

Comment: press `f12` key and check if the console is showing any error

Comment: Given that this code doesn't work as presented, can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: There are no errors in developer mode, neither in console or elements tabs.

Comment: Can you show the part of your html where you include the bootstrap and jquery files?

Comment: I added the bootstrap and jquery links.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 possible causes of your problems, given that no errors are shown in your console.

- `JQuery` could have been loaded twice.

  - check for inclusions of files which may already have been included in the others.
- The `.js` files which you are referencing might not be in the right order,

  - make sure JQuery is loaded and only then Bootstrap .
- Your `JQuery` doesn't work well with your current `Bootstrap` version. Try upgrading either of the 2 or both.